# Does BeanIO require I provide a setter

Tags: bean-io

It appears BeanIO requires I provide setters for my fields.  Is this necessary?  I created a BeanIO writer, I intend only to write files, and I have getters for each field - why would I need setters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your beans are only meant to be *serialized* (i.e. used by a `BeanWriter`), you can declare your stream as `mode="write"`. This will cause BeanIO to look for getters but not setters.

The [reference guide](https://beanio.github.io/docs/reference-guide/#a7-stream) states that:

> By default, a stream mapping can be used for both reading input streams and writing output streams, called `readwrite` mode. Setting mode to read orwrite instead, respectively restricts usage to a `BeanReader` or a `BeanWriter` only, but relaxes some validations on the mapping configuration.
>
> When `mode` is set to `read`, a bean class does not require getter methods.
>
> When `mode` is set to `write`, a bean class may be abstract or an interface, and does not require setter methods.